# seaborn violin plot for single column splitting by a categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    num_column    is_train
    30.75               1
    12.05               1 
    ..                 ..
    43.79               0         
    15.35               0
```

I want to see the distribution of `num_column` using a violin plot and with each side(or split) of the violin showing the data for each of my two categories in `is_train` column.

From the [examples in documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html), here's what I could come up with:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.violinplot(x=merged_data.loc[:,'num_column'], hue=merged_data.loc[:,'is_train'], split=True)
```

From the result of this, I could see that the arguments `hue` and `split` had no effect at all. Meaning sides of the violin weren't split and I couldn't see any legend, so I presumed `hue` argument had no effect.

I am trying to compare distributions of a column from my train and test data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `split=` argument is to be used with `hue`-nesting, which can only be used if you already have an `x=` argument. Therefore you need to provide columns for both `x` (should be the same value for both datasets) and `hue` (coded depending on the dataset):

```
merged_data['dummy'] = 0
sns.violinplot(data=merged_data, y='num_column', split=True, hue='is_train', x='dummy')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `x=` parameter to create multiple violins. The `hue` and `split` parameters are used when a differentiation via a third column is needed.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

merged_data = pd.DataFrame({'num_column': 20 + np.random.randn(1000).cumsum(),
                            'is_train': np.repeat([0, 1], 500)})
sns.violinplot(data=merged_data, x='is_train', y='num_column')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]